# Angular 6 SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<

Tags: angular

I am working on an angular website.

Here is my production package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^9.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "angular2-cookie-law": "^1.4.0",
    "angular2-qrcode": "^2.0.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^3.0.3",
    "ng2-ui-auth": "^8.0.1",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^0.1.24",
    "ngx-img-cropper": "^0.9.7",
    "ngx-slider": "0.0.5",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.18",
    "ngx-device-detector" : "1.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.5.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.2",
    "@types/node": "~8.0.53",
    "codelyzer": "~4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.2.0",
    "sw-precache": "^5.2.0",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "^0.11.4",
    "ts-node": "~3.3.0",
    "tslint": "^5.8.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
```

I decided to migrate to ng6 on my tests servers:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.10",
    "@ncstate/sat-popover": "^2.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^10.0.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "angular2-cookie-law": "^6.0.4",
    "angular2-qrcode": "^2.0.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^4.2.1",
    "ng2-ui-auth": "^9.0.1",
    "ngx-device-detector": "1.3.3",
    "ngx-file-drop": "^4.0.6",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^1.2.2",
    "ngx-slider": "0.0.5",
    "rxjs": "6.0.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.8.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.10",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.2",
    "@types/node": "~8.0.53",
    "codelyzer": "~4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.2.0",
    "sw-precache": "^5.2.0",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "^0.11.4",
    "ts-node": "~3.3.0",
    "tslint": "^5.8.0",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2"
  }
```

Since I did thoses changes I am getting error after any new changes (on firefox but as well on chrome):

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<  main.<hash>.js:1
```

After looking at the file it seems that  main..js is returning me the index.html (so I understand why it complains)

**Let's take an example:**

**At Vn**: I have main.c26c44b8b53d610233a3.js referenced in the index.html.

I am doing a change in my ts file. Rebuild and push my changes.

**At Vn+1**: I am supposed to have main.a6b91500af09e35296c4.js referenced in the index.html

I reopen the browser and I am getting error:

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<  main.c26c44b8b53d610233a3.js:1
```

When I look at the index.html I have main.c26c44b8b53d610233a3.js still referenced.

Then when I refresh, the page is well displayed (because new hash is taken)

For information my:

```
<base href="/">
```

I never changed my build mechanism. I always runned:

```
ng build --prod && sw-precache --root=dist --config=precache-config.js
```

Do you have any idea why now I am getting this error ? I never got this error with angular 5.

Thanks in advance

> Edit: This is not from time to time. In fact it concerns any changes I am doing on the js

Regards

Comment: are you using any `<script>` tag to load external `.js`?

Comment: No I am not using any script tag. I just have the polyfills main and runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the route cause of the issue.

Since I migrated to angular 6 the bundle of my app is now 2.97 MB which exceed the maximum sixe of sw-precache default value (2.1)

I found in the log of my build:

```
Skipping static resource "dist/main.fd245775d6e1690d968f.js" (2.97 MB) - max size is 2.1 MB
```

This results in the fact that we let the browser handling the caching.

To fix this just adding the following line in the precache config fix the problem:

```
maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes: 10485760,
```

Comment: where's the precache config?

Comment: More information is needed here.